# Unison on bootup

Tags: cron, boot, executable, rc.local

I have unison running thru a config file by default. In here it applies the `wait=watch` function so it syncs automatically. But I wanted to run unison on boot, but I haven't been able to do this.

There were some other links, but they didn't gave me an answer.

Things I tried:

Applying (with proper rights) unison to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` and specifying the absolute path. Basicly: `/usr/local/bin/unison` &
when I executed `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` or `/etc/rc.local` manually, everything works like a charm.

Applying to cron by doing: `crontab -e`, and than `@restart /usr/local/bin/unison` &

writing a (working) `.sh` script that executes unison and putting this in `rc.local` or `cron`.

I also applied it to `chkconfig` with rights `2345` (yes it's listed when running `chkconfig --list-all`)

I'm running out of ideas. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a sh script:

```
nano unisonMonitor.sh

#! /bin/bash

su – root -c /usr/local/bin/unison default &

make it executable with 

chmod +x unisonMonitor.sh

cd /etc/rc.d

nano rc.local

#! /bin/bash

touch /var/lock/subsys/local
sleep 6
/unisonMonitor.sh

chmod u+x


systemctl restart rc-local
systemctl status rc-local


reboot

login → ps aux | grep unison
```

This eventually worked for me.